# Latching relay - Remember state after power failure

Tags: arduino, relay, home-automation

I am trying to use a relay to control appliances. My arduino will trigger the relay on/off. Additional requirement is in case of power failure the relay should be able to maintain its state so that it is in same state when power comes back. Ex: Arduino turned on the lamp (using relay), power failed, power is back, the lamp is in ON state.

I read about them quite a bit and found out that I need a Latching relay. I tried to find them online and stores(vetco, radio shack) but all I find is bulky things. Are there any latching relays that are similar in form factor to regular ones?

Also any other alternate options to make my requirement possible without a latching relay?

Comment: Usually power relays need to be bulky to handle potential current.  How many amps are you looking to switch?

Comment: An alternative would be save the last state on EEPROM, and then if it was ON, turn the appliance ON after x seconds when power comes back up. This can diminish the exposure of your appliance to ON/OFF cycles during failures.

Comment: Asking "Are there any latching relays that are similar in form factor to regular ones?" makes this a shopping question

Comment: @Seth I'm planning to use it for home appliances. As far as i know most of them are upto 10 amps.

Comment: Right, so there you are either 120VAC or 240VAC, which means extra insulation and at 10amps, extra conductor.  I'd be surprised to find anything smaller than about 15mmx30mmx15mm.  And that goes for non-latching as well, so @JackCreasey's answer won't help you here.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you would want to go down the path of latching relays.
You have an Arduino that when powered on can turn the power to your devices on and off ....you also have EEPROM in your Arduino, so could save the current state of devices to EEPROM. 
And when you startup after a power failure...if there are values in the EEPROM....restore them.

You might want to consider whether you restore all values or just selected items since you may have power failures when you are not present....just a thought.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jack. In my scenario 4 or more switches are controlled by one arduino. That means a typical EEPROM with 100K write cycles would mean - 25K per switch. Which is too less. Also can there be cases where the power failures happen exactly after i write to EEPROM but before i actually do that on the appliance in which case my EEPROM has a wrong value. What is your opinion on this?

Comment: Even 100k writes total (and they are conservative numbers) and 25k writes per channel would seem to provide 6-7 years use at 10 state changes a day. The other thing to consider is that the 100K writes is per locations so spread across all the locations you have an aggregate of millions of writes to the EEPROM area. You only need 1 bit for the state change of each channel, and you can implement wear leveling if you want. In the very crudest of implementations you could use 3 bytes...two for write counts and one for status. When the count reaches 65K stop using that block of three.

Comment: The Atmel 328 used in Arduino has 1K of EEPROM. Using the crude method I proposed above and 3 location groups with only total writes of 65K writes per group this would provide a little over 22 millions individual state changes...would that be enough for your application? And you have a whole byte for current state, so could handle 8 switches.

Comment: That is an amazing analysis Jack. Using locations totally slipped off my mind. 22 million is more than i need. One problem still remains though - power failure between state change and actual action. In that case I will have an in-consistent state in memory

Comment: A simple way to implement that is of course to use the A/D convertor to measure your (unregulated) Vin voltage. Since you control the amount of capacitance on the Vin you can control the drop rate of the voltage. Before writing to EEPROM you look to see if the Vin is above your power fail threshold. If it is do the 3 byte write (assured by the Vin capacity), if the voltage is below your power fail threshold, post an error and maybe beep.  .....Setting Vin capacitance to allow say 500-1000 mS holdup time before the processor resets give more than ample time to assure your write to EEPROM

Comment: A typical relay is only going to last 100K operations at full load, so having an EEPROM that lasts much more than 10x that seems like a waste of time and effort. Many external SEEPROMs such as the AT24C01D are rated at 1,000,000 write cycles. They cost about a dime and hang off the I2C bus.

Answer (score 1):

Latching relays are available in DIP form-factor.  For example there are two different kinds available from All Electronics right now. You did not reveal what is your load (current, power, voltage, etc.) so we don't know what size relay you are looking for??

You could also use non-volatile memory to store the state. You could use an ordinary flip-flop/latch backed up by a coin cell (or a couple of AA cells, etc.)  Some microcontrollers have some available NVRAM (non-volatile memory) available for storing status, etc.  Some auxillary chips like clock/calendar chips have some available non-volatile memory available for you to use.

Comment: Thanks for the info Richard. My use case should cover all home appliances ranging from a lamp to refrigerators and washers/dryers. 220V voltage, ~15 amps

Comment: There are certainly mechanically latching relays (separate coils for SET and for RESET) that could handle significant mains loads. But we don't know what you consider "bulky".  Mains-rated and "bulky" may not be separable.

Answer (score 1):

Using a latching relay means that when power is restored, it is immediately available at the appliance. Using a retentive state in the controller energizing a regular relay means there will be a delay on the re-application of power to the appliance. Each scenario has its pluses and minuses, you need to thoroughly vet those before making a decision as to which way to go. Nobody can answer that for you without full detailed knowledge of what you are trying to accomplish and why.

If you want to go with a latching relay, it requires either two coils, a Latch and Unlatch coil, meaning two signals as well, or it requires a relay with a complicated mechanical toggle mechanism that alternates the state of the contacts with each successive pulse of the coil. Either way, it requires real estate to make it happen.